# logger.info(traceback.print_exc()) coming on python gui

Tags: python, logging

When I execute `logger.info(traceback.print_exc())`
the trace gets on console rather than in the log file
I have `logger.propagate = False` also still the same issue

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`print_exc` prints the stack trace to stderr.

Just use the exc_info=1 argument and it will automaticaly include the exception.

```
logging.exception("Exception") #or 
logging.error("exception ",exc_info=1) #or
logging.info("Exception has occured" ,exc_info=1)
```

Comment: I am getting an exception at exc_info  . on googling I found sys.exc_info() are these 2 same

Answer (score 3):

I am using python 2.7 and sadly `exc_info=1` never worked for me so I had to use this:

```
  import traceback
  ...


  log.debug(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: there was an issue with it with old Python 2.7 versioins.